# Как на PHP преобразовать число 1e-8 в строку без знака?

Tags: php

Данные получаю в виде такой строки, нужно получить float число без знака в виде строки

```
$value = "1e-8";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$value = "1e-8";
$float_value = (float)$value;
$abs_value = abs($float_value);
$result = number_format($abs_value, 8, '.', '');
```

Этот код преобразует строку `$value` в число с плавающей точкой, затем берет абсолютное значение этого числа, а затем преобразует его обратно в строку.

Comment: Через функцию `number_format` вроде работает `$value = rtrim(rtrim(number_format((float) $value, 10, '.', ''), '0'), '.');` незнаю только на сколько хорошо это работает